# How to import the MySQL data from Windows to Hadoop file system?

Tags: hadoop

Here is my code in sqoop to import the data:

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://my_ip/databasename --username $USER_NAME --password $PASSWORD$ --table tablename --m 1
```

this gives the following error message from server:

```
Host 'Dell-PC' is not allowed to connect to this MariaDB server
```

Comment: you need to grant priviledges to user that is trying to connect to mysql

Answer (score 0):

The above sqoop command tries to connect to mysql server , it should be replaced with respective db.

Comment: jdbc:mysql://my_ip/databasename... displays the database as mysql

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure that your credentials are correct (You have your password specified as --password $PASSWORD$ , is the second $ a typo?)  If they are, you should check to verify that remote client access is enabled in MariaDB.